# Running jquery from the url

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to know if there is any possible method to run jquery script from the url on the target page.

```
for e.g.
<a href="helpme.html?<script>$(document).ready(funtion(){
$('.helper').addClass('.nonhelper');
});</script>">HELPER</a>
```

I know the code I have written is jibberish but I hope it is able to communicate what I wish to achieve from the link.

Comment: append a variable to the URL then test if it's present or not then your run the code. As a side note, if sush method was available, all the website will be hacked

Comment: do you want to run js code in **helpme.html** page?

Comment: thanks everyone I figured out a solution that kinda worked for me.